# getting stuck in binary search algorithm program

Tags: python, module, binary-search

I am getting bug in this program. I run the program easily not getting any error but the result is having some bug and I am not able to find it. I am running this code on pycharm.

'''

```
""" Binary Search Algorithm
----------------------------------------
"""
#// iterative implementation of binary search in Python
def binary_search(a_list, item):
    """Performs iterative binary search to find the position of an integer in a given, sorted, list.
    a_list -- sorted list of integers
    item -- integer you are searching for the position of
    """
    first = 0
    last = len(a_list) - 1
    while first <= last:
        i = (first + last) / 2
        if a_list[i] == item:
            return ' found at position '.format(item=item, i=i)
        elif a_list[i] > item:
            last = i - 1
        elif a_list[i] < item:
            first = i + 1
        else:
            return ' not found in the list'.format(item=item)
#// recursive implementation of binary search in Python
def binary_search_recursive(a_list, item):
    """Performs recursive binary search of an integer in a given, sorted, list.
    a_list -- sorted list of integers
    item -- integer you are searching for the position of
    """
    first = 0
    last = len(a_list) - 1
    if len(a_list) == 0:
        return ' was not found in the list'.format(item=item)
    else:
        i = (first + last) // 2
        if item == a_list[i]:
            return ' found'.format(item=item)
        else:
            if a_list[i] < item:
                return binary_search_recursive(a_list[i+1:], item)
            else:
                return binary_search_recursive(a_list[:i], item)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work and actually gives me some errors. After fixing them, I manages to get iterative and recursive binary functions that look like this:

```python
""" Binary Search Algorithm
----------------------------------------
"""
#// iterative implementation of binary search in Python
# Iterative Binary Search Function 
# It returns index of x in given array arr if present, 
# else returns -1 
def binary_search(arr, x): 
    low = 0
    high = len(arr) - 1
    mid = 0

    while low <= high: 

        mid = (high + low) // 2

        # Check if x is present at mid 
        if arr[mid] < x: 
            low = mid + 1

        # If x is greater, ignore left half 
        elif arr[mid] > x: 
            high = mid - 1

        # If x is smaller, ignore right half 
        else: 
            return mid 

    # If we reach here, then the element was not present 
    return -1


# Test array 
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ] 
x = 10

# Function call 
result = binary_search(arr, x) 

if result != -1: 
    print("Element is present at index", str(result)) 
else: 
    print("Element is not present in array") 

def recursive_binary_search(arr, target):
    mid = len(arr) // 2
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return mid if arr[mid] == target else None
    elif arr[mid] == target:
        return mid
    else:
        if arr[mid] < target:
            callback_response = recursive_binary_search((arr[mid:]), target)
            return mid + callback_response if callback_response is not None else None
        else:
            return recursive_binary_search((arr[:mid]), target)

# Test array 
arr = [ 2, 3, 4, 10, 40 ] 
x = 10

# Function call 
result = recursive_binary_search(arr, x) 

if result != -1: 
    print("Element is present at index", str(result)) 
else: 
    print("Element is not present in array")
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude. your code is working properly and its understood as well. But I was trying to get results with random  binary functions. By the way thank you so much

Comment: No problem hope it helps you!